# Is there an idiom or expression to say "when something is beyond your understanding, you think very little of it"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

For example:

A: Your taste in movies sucks, Jared.

B: ... (that idiom/expression)

Maybe something like "you can't expect a ... to appreciate the greatness of a ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B would like to tell A: ***Don't talk about things you don't know anything about***. B may think that A is an ***ultracrepidarian***, a person expressing opinions on matters outside the scope of one’s knowledge or expertise (used as a noun or adjective).

The site [Wordhistories](https://wordhistories.net/2018/02/03/ultracrepidarian-meaning-origin/) shows that:

> This word was specifically invented to qualify the English poet and
> critic William Gifford (1756-1826). With reference to the fact that William Gifford had been a shoemaker’s
> apprentice, ***ultracrepidarian*** alludes to the remark “ne supra crepidam
> sutor iudicaret”, “***the cobbler should not judge beyond his shoe***”,
> attributed to the painter Apelles in response to criticism about the shape of shoes he painted from a
> shoemaker. This anecdote is the origin of
> the proverb ***Let the cobbler stick to his last***.

This proverb is mainly American and it means:

> people should only concern themselves with things they know something about. ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03CxNVXyPRWjAkb6j32Vk3MDIj76Q%3A1611050491532&ei=-60GYNz6H7TMxgPep7PIDg&q=let%20the%20cobbler%20stick%20to%20his%20last&oq=let%20t&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMggIABDJAxCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyAgguOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6AggAOgUILhCxAzoLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6CAguELEDEIMBOgUIABCxAzoECC4QQ1DyMVivOGDVRmgAcAF4AIAB6AGIAcQGkgEFMC40LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab))

or

> Do not advise about or interfere with matters of which you know little or nothing. ([Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cobbler%2C+stick+to+your+last))

Here are some other funny options of what B may say to A, which may not cover precisely your meaning, but would work just fine in your context:

> ***Better to remain silent and be thought a fool, than to open your mouth
> and remove all doubt.***
>
> ***A little knowledge is a dangerous thing***.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **tone-deaf**, which Merriam-Webster defines as:

> having or showing an obtuse insensitivity or lack of perception particularly in matters of public sentiment, opinion, or taste

*The White House long ago concluded that she is aloof and politically tone-deaf.*

— Michael Duffy

Therefore, the dialogue could be rendered as:

> A: Your taste in movies sucks, Jared.

> Jared: Well, this could be because I'm **aesthetically tone-deaf.**